# Restrict the Joda timer to be not dependent with system time

Tags: java, swing, timer, jodatime, clock

I am making a Payroll and Attendance Monitoring system as a school project.
Currently using Java Swing with Joda API.
I'm in a part of attendance monitoring.
I want a security restriction that even the user change the system time he can't cheat to time-out early.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trusting anything from the user's computer, that's a bad start IMO. (What's to stop the user from manually modifying the data recorded?) Normally a server which you *can* trust would be involved. However, that's a different matter and I appreciate this is a school project.

To address the question as asked though - if you can't trust anything locally, you should probably look into an internet time provider. There's nothing Joda Time specific about this - you *may* find "Joda Time integrated" libraries to talk to [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) servers, but I think it's more likely that you'll just get libraries which expose a number of milliseconds (or microseconds, or nanoseconds) since some epoch in a vanilla way. It should be easy to construct the relevant Joda Time types from there. Just be careful that you don't use Joda Time types which *implicitly* use local settings (not just the clock - consider the time zone too!).

Answer (score 0):

Well your school has maybe no sysadmin who can block unauthorized access on the installed computers. So a workaround could be to implement the interface

[DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider.html)

and then install it by [DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisProvider(...)](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisProvider%28org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider%29)

The right (secure) implementation of the interface should use an SNTP-server (for example [Apache-NTP-client](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ntp/NTPClient.java&ei=1oU1U_7mFIHYtAbvqoGoBw&usg=AFQjCNG8kV429WndH-cjeJ4bA_yeTX24KA&bvm=bv.63808443,d.Yms)) via internet (if this is possible on the school). Otherwise every clock based on `System.currentTimeMillis()` is sensible for external clock adjustments.